# How to stop scroll in current position?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

In my app i need to scroll user's page to up until the spinners reach the top of screen and then scroll up only postfeed. So posts will be in the scrollview, but what i need to do to stop all page scroll at the spinners on top? Can you give me xml-layout code and java if it necessary too.

[My user's page link](http://postimg.org/image/8v0jvxtnh/)

Comment: I have the same question, if you found a solution share with me, thank's.